# How to iterate the response in ng

Tags: angularjs

I have the above response in $scope but when I iterate using ng-repeat I am not able to see the results.

```
$scope.datas = {"groupActivity[{"name":"Karthikeyan","activity":"Walking","duration":"10","date":1416996547995{"name":"Andrea","activity":"Swimming","duration":"20","date":1416996547995}],"group":null}
```

In html I tried like below

```
<div ng-repeat = values in datas>
<h4> The name is {{values.groupActivity.name}} </h4>
 </div>
```

But, in the place of directive nothing is being displayed. Can you help what is the mistake I did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $scope.datas object wasn't well formatted. Please see below for working solutions

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.datas = {
    groupActivity: [{
      "name": "Karthikeyan ",
      "activity ": "Walking ",
      "duration ": "10 ",
      "date ": 1416996547995
    }, {
      "name": "Andrea ",
      "activity ": "Swimming ",
      "duration ": "20 ",
      "date ": 1416996547995
    }],

    "group": null
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="values in datas.groupActivity">
      <h4> The name is {{values.name}} </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```